# Refine selection of multiple select elements with array of objects using ng-options

Tags: angularjs

Say I have an array of objects:

```
var people = [
  {name: "person 1", favouriteThing: 'pizza'},
  {name: "person 1", favouriteThing: 'vegetables'},
  {name: "person 2", favouriteThing: 'spinach'},
  {name: "person 2", favouriteThing: 'kimchi'},
];
```

I want to be able to refine this data with select elements so that the first element would only contain 'person 1' and 'person 2' as options (no duplicates). After 'person 1' is selected, pizza and vegetables should be available in the second select element.

Here's what I currently have for the select elements:

```
<select ng-options="person.name for person in people" ng-model="name"></select>

<select ng-options="person.favouriteThing group by name for person in people"></select>
```

Just hoping for some input on the approach I should take. Maybe I should be using an object more like this? (not ideal for my situation)

```
var people = [
  {name: "person 1", 
   favouriteThings: ['pizza', 'vegetables']
  },
  {name: "person 2", 
   favouriteThings: ['spinach', 'kimchi']
  }
];
```

Comment: I will suggest you use underscoreJS to filter your array, and push all the unique value inside another array. This way you will not get duplicate values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/fHEatUICX4roK5OPLftV?p=preview)

you can have two solution

(1) Load single select with group by 'name' property.

```
<select ng-options="person.favouriteThing  group by person.name for person  in c.people" ng-model="name"></select>
```

(2) Load two different select. One with name and one with favoriteThing. On change of name you can load favorite thing.

```
<select ng-options="person.name for person in c.getPeopleName()" ng-model="personName"></select>
<select ng-options="person.favouriteThing for person  in c.getFavoriteThing(personName)" ng-model="favoriteThing"></select>


  this.getPeopleName = function () {
      return _.uniq(this.people, function (item) {return item.name;})
  };

  this.getFavoriteThing = function (people) {
    var arr = [];
    _.each(this.people, function (item) {
      if(item.name === people.name) {
        arr.push(item);
      }
    });

    return arr;
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the unique value use undrescore,

```
$scope.personName =_.uniq(people, function(person) { return person.name; });
```